# sorting of list of lists in python

Tags: python

how can i sort a list of list in python with use of bubble sort datewise??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sorted.` with `lambda` in `key`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
l = [['sana', '2017-09-11', '76', '5af50d3b6528870010a42a1c', '', ''], ['sana', '2018-05-11', '75', '5af50e046528870010a42a1d', '', ''], ['sana', '2017-11-11', '70', '5af50e8a6528870010a42a1e', '', ''], ['sana', '2018-05-11', '75', '5af50f106528870010a42a1f', '', ''], ['sanath29kumar', '2018-09-19', '82', '5af50f806528870010a42a20', '', ''], ['sanath29kumar', '2017-08-11', '81', '5af5105e6528870010a42a22', '', '']]
print( sorted(l, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1], "%Y-%m-%d")) )
```